# Can I publish a book set in the Harry Potter universe?

Tags: fantasy, fan-fiction

I know similar questions have been asked.
But also, consider that I want to publish a book in countries other than the US or UK.

Comment: Copyright law exists in Eastern Europe and Russia just like in the Rest of the world. There are very few countries who aren't signatories to the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention).

Comment: Friendly reminder that answerers should **support their answers** and explain why they are correct rather than just stating an opinion. Reference to actual copyright law or examples of existing works are a good start.

Answer (score 8):

**No.**

Since Harry Potter has not been around nearly long enough to be public domain, and copyright law is a thing.

But also **Yes.**

IF you get permission from the person who owns the original content to write a spinoff (In this case I'm assuming J.K Rowling)... Good luck with that.

Answer (score 3):

**It depends on how lax copyright laws and enforcement are in your country.**

A number of unofficial Harry Potter novels have appeared in non-English-speaking countries, to cash in on the craze. Some of these may be parodies.

[Here's a list](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/31430/13-brazen-harry-potter-knock-offs-around-world), some of the titles are pretty off the wall.

Comment: hahaha those are some hilarious book titles and descriptions. Is some of those actually worth reading?

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to tell your story and change just enough of the setting to make it your own. You'll then have a novel you could, potentially, publish.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it on a fan fiction website. Otherwise it’s plagiarism and copyright if you don’t get the author’s permission to publish it.

Comment: But if it's good I want to publish, I don't care about revenue

Comment: HI Leila, to properly support this answer you will need to provide a reference or some other evidence to support that this is plagiarism. Currently this is just a statement of opinion. Try referencing copyright laws or similar framework. Good luck and happy writing!

Answer (score 1):

You can't publish a book explicitly set in a world created by another author without appropriate permissions, which you will not get.

Most authors and publishers turn a blind eye to fan fiction AS LONG AS IT IS NOT MONETIZED. But the moment you try to make money from this, you are stealing someone else's intellectual property.

With that said, Harry Potter didn't invent the idea of a magical world or magical school. You could certainly publish a book about a magic world existing alongside the mundane one, as long as Harry Potter characters and settings don't make appearances. No schools named "Hogwarts" or "Beauxbatons." Use HP as an inspiration --don't copy it.

Comment: Better yet, go find what inspired JKR. Hint: It wasn't fantasy novels.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it on a fan page without permission and you wouldn't get in trouble. But otherwise you'd have to get permission from the original creator. If you do that though you're all good!